# Configuring Geoserver to work on an Azure app service

Tags: java, geoserver

I have an Azure app service (Tomcat 9.0 & Java 11) configured with AD authentication and I have deployed the Geoserver 2.18 WAR onto it.

When I try to access geoserver I get the home page ok but when I try to login with the default geoserver credentials I get a stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to parse address1.2.3.4, 5.6.7.8, 9.10.11.12
    org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.IpAddressMatcher.parseAddress(IpAddressMatcher.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.IpAddressMatcher.matches(IpAddressMatcher.java:66)
    org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.IpAddressMatcher.matches(IpAddressMatcher.java:62)
    org.geoserver.security.BruteForceListener.lambda$requestAddressInWhiteList$0(BruteForceListener.java:126)
    java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$1MatchSink.accept(Unknown Source)
    java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.anyMatch(Unknown Source)
    org.geoserver.security.BruteForceListener.requestAddressInWhiteList(BruteForceListener.java:126)
    org.geoserver.security.BruteForceListener.onApplicationEvent(BruteForceListener.java:65)
    org.geoserver.security.BruteForceListener.onApplicationEvent(BruteForceListener.java:28)
org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:403)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher.publishAuthenticationSuccess(DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher.java:99)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:224)
    org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityManager$1.authenticate(GeoServerSecurityManager.java:315)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:122)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:101)
    org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
    org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:47)
    org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
    org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    com.microsoft.azure.appservice.filters.AppServiceFilter.doFilter(AppServiceFilter.java:53)
    com.microsoft.azure.appservice.EasyAuthFilter.doFilter(EasyAuthFilter.java:42)
```

(I have replaced the 3 IP's in the stack trace with dummy IP's for privacy reasons)

Checking the HTTP headers that Azure's authentication proxy is sending to geoserver and the string of 3 IP's in the `x-forwarded-for` HTTP header matches ok.

Have I failed to configure something? Its a bit difficult to get at the geoserver security settings since I can't login!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after some deeper digging think I've found a solution. Geoserver uses IpAddressMatcher in its brute force login prevention. IpAddressMatcher expects a single IP address in the HTTP headers. Azure has multiple so this causes the issue.

The brute force login detection can be disabled by editing $GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/security/config.xml and near the bottom change bruteForcePrevention to false like so:

```
  <bruteForcePrevention>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
    <minDelaySeconds>1</minDelaySeconds>
    <maxDelaySeconds>5</maxDelaySeconds>
    <maxBlockedThreads>100</maxBlockedThreads>
    <whitelistedMasks>
      <string>127.0.0.1</string>
    </whitelistedMasks>
  </bruteForcePrevention>
```

Restart tomcat and now geoserver works and I can login.

Comment: How did GeoServer run in app service? would you recommend?

Comment: @Progger Its working OK for us, but I haven't had enough experience with it yet to give a meaningful comparison vs running it on a Linux VM. There are many extra considerations for running geoserver in production, and these would be better suited to another question.

Comment: @Ralph how do you make sure GeoServer configuration info/files is persistent? I know that everything in the `/home` directory is kept between server restarts, but GeoServer configuration files (like web.xml) is stored outside of `/home` and inside the `/usr` directory which is wiped upon restart. This means I lose all my config info (passwords, workspaces, data stores, layers).

Comment: @TheoF That would be better suited to another question but basically you put the geoserver config folder on Azure storage and then mount the azure storage on your app service while setting the environment variable for geoserver to point at the mountpoint.

Comment: @Ralph I think it’s even easier, from recent testing I’ve done. SSH into the app, copy the geoserver data folder to a location in \home, then in Azure set the GEOSERVER_DATA environment variable to point to that new directory.

Answer (score 0):

I found java 1.8.0_181 is the latest version of java I can use while loading GeoServer to Azure's Web App Service. I currently am using Java 8, Minor version Java 1.8.0_181 with Apache Tomcat 9.0.46. It appears they dropped oracle after this version and there maybe some type of dependency that causes you not to be able to run anything higher than that version in Azure (GeoServer supports Java 11). I'd love to know if anyone has ever found the exact dependency required! I would also love to know if Azure will re-implement those dependencies so users can move to Java 11!!! I hope this helps you to implement GeoServer in Azure Web Apps

Comment: Hi Billie, welcome to Stack Overflow! The answers section should be used for providing answers for the current open question. If you don't find it is solving your issue you can try for searching similar questions as the problem you have. If this still doesn't help, try posting a new question with all the necessary details of what is your setup and what you have tried so far.

Comment: The official docs say Java 11 ir required: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/installation/index.html#installation